WPF DevExpress : adding hierarchical data template not binding well
I have some code for handling competency and sub-competencies:
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace opr.Pages
{
    public partial class TeamsAdmin : Page
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Competency> Competencies { get; set; }

        public TeamsAdmin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            LoadData();
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            var allCompetencies = new ObservableCollection<Competency>
            {
                new Competency { Id = "0000000001", ParentId = null, Name = "REVIZIJA", Description = "", Ordinal = 4, State = true },
                new Competency { Id = "0000000002", ParentId = null, Name = "RAČUNOVODSVO", Description = "", Ordinal = 3, State = true },
                new Competency { Id = "0000000003", ParentId = null, Name = "POREZI", Description = "", Ordinal = 2, State = true },
                new Competency { Id = "0000000004", ParentId = null, Name = "INTERNA REVIZIJA", Description = "Probni opis", Ordinal = 1, State = true },
                new Competency { Id = "0000000005", ParentId = null, Name = "POSLOVNO SAVETOVANJE", Description = "", Ordinal = 10, State = true },
                new Competency { Id = "0000000006", ParentId = "0000000001", Name = "Statutarna revizija", Description = "", Ordinal = 0, State = true },
                new Competency { Id = "0000000007", ParentId = "0000000001", Name = "Dobrovoljna revizija", Description = "", Ordinal = 0, State = true },
                new Competency { Id = "0000000008", ParentId = "0000000001", Name = "Revizija projekta", Description = "", Ordinal = 0, State = true },
                new Competency { Id = "0000000009", ParentId = "0000000001", Name = "Finansijski pregled", Description = "", Ordinal = 0, State = true },
                new Competency { Id = "0000000010", ParentId = "0000000001", Name = "Finansijski due diligence", Description = "", Ordinal = 0, State = true },
                new Competency { Id = "0000000011", ParentId = "0000000001", Name = "Revizija grupnog paketa", Description = "", Ordinal = 0, State = true }
            };

            var rootCompetencies = new ObservableCollection<Competency>(
                allCompetencies.Where(c => c.ParentId == null)
                    .Select(c => new Competency
                    {
                        Id = c.Id,
                        ParentId = c.ParentId,
                        Name = c.Name,
                        Description = c.Description,
                        Ordinal = c.Ordinal,
                        State = c.State,
                        SubCompetencies = new ObservableCollection<Competency>(
                            allCompetencies.Where(sub => sub.ParentId == c.Id))
                    })
            );

            Competencies = rootCompetencies;

            treeListCompetencies.ItemsSource = Competencies;
        }
    }

    public class Competency
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Ordinal { get; set; }
        public bool State { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Competency> SubCompetencies { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Competency>();
    }
}

And here is the XAML:
<Page x:Class="opr.Pages.TeamsAdmin"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:opr.Pages"
      Title="TeamsAdmin">

    <Page.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Competency}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubCompetencies}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <dxg:TreeListControl x:Name="treeListCompetencies"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="None"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Competencies}">
            <dxg:TreeListControl.View>
                <dxg:TreeListView TreeDerivationMode="HierarchicalDataTemplate" />
            </dxg:TreeListControl.View>
        </dxg:TreeListControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>

As you can see on the example screenshot, it generates ok the structure, but something regarding the bindings for the name is not good.
I want to preview name for competency and subcompetency. How can I do that?

